# Universal Property

Tags: field-theory

> Show that if $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$, then $F$ contains (an isomorphic copy of) $\mathbb{Q}$.

A field is a ring and since a ring with charecteristic $0$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ we get that $\mathbb{Z}\subset F$.  So by the universal property we get 
    $$
    \mathbb{Z}\to \operatorname{Frac}(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Q}\cong F
    $$

The above is true but the question says that $F$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ so apparently I'm missing something.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you deducing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $F$? all the universal property gives you is that there is a map from $\mathbb{Q} \to F$ extending the map from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $F$.

Comment: You're right.  My notes on the universal property were wrong.  Problem solved.  Thanks!